# Rails - get image asset path without specifying asset

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-select2, select2-rails

Is there anyway to simply get the image asset directory without having to specify a specific asset?

In Rails 3.2 I had the below in my **js.erb** file:

`var image_path = "<%= asset_path('" + image.id.toLowerCase() +"') %>"`

This would allow me to display images in a select menu using select2. Since upgrading to Rails 4 this no longer works (in development as well as production) and will throw an error that the file is not found. I assume this is because my erb is being called before my js, therefore it has no image name to look for. I don't know why this worked in Rails 3.2 though.

I thought as a work around I could get the default asset image path in js and then add my image name to it. For example:

```
#.js.erb
var image_directory = <%= image_asset_path %>
var current_image_path = image_directory + image.id.toLowerCase()
```